# Bootstrap toggle sidebar point the active tab from outside tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap toggle sidebar to my website. I am using `nav-pills` inside the sidebar.  I want to active and point the exact tab follow home,profile,contact. If I click home nav exactly point to the home tab panel after open sidebar.

I have tried below script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('#dismiss, .overlay').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
        $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
    });

    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').addClass('active'); 
        var tab = e.target.hash;
            $('.tab-content .tab-pane' + tab + '"]').tab("active");             
    });
});
```

My code [here](http://orderonline.my/designer/test/sidebar/)

screenshot for ref:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll quickly go through the main problems of your question.

1. You're missing the function parameter
   --
   In your

   ...).on('click', function () {
   ...
   var tab = e.target...

`e` is not defined. It's supposed to be the function parameter (a.k.a. as `event`, or `e`):

```
...).on('click', function (e) {
        ...
        var tab = e.target...
```

2. You have invalid markup
   --
   Another **big** problem with your code is you have duplicate ids in your page. You can't have more than one single element in the page having the same `id`. When you need to assign behavior or styling to more than one element, use **class**es, not **id**s.
3. You modified the library's markup
   --
   Going further down, even if you fix the missing parameter and duplicated ids problems, you'll quickly find out `e.target` does not have a `hash` property, because the target is no longer an anchor tag `<a>`, but a `<span>`. Why? Most likely, you changed it, as you thought it looks better as a `<span>`, wrapped in a `<button>`. Maybe it does, but you could easily make it look the same by applying `btn btn-info` classes to the `<a>`, without breaking the library's functionality.
4. You haven't read the documentation
   --
   What's nice about Bootstrap Sidebar is that, unlike for other, more shady libraries, which just provide you with some code and not explain everything, for this one you can find a quality, highly-detailed [tutorial](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar) on how it all works and what your options in implementing it are.

That tutorial was written for you. After you read and apply it, if you still have trouble using the library, update your question.